# Make x3dom 3D non draggable

Tags: x3d, x3dom

I have created a surface-plot using X3DOm. I want to fix its position. How to make the 3D objects created using x3dom as not draggable or rotatable. I want to fix it. Please assist.

Answer (score 1):

you need to change the `type` field of the `NavigationInfo` element to `NONE`.

Find documentation [here](http://www.web3d.org/documents/specifications/19775-1/V3.2/Part01/components/navigation.html#NavigationInfo).